# Iframe content with cURL in WordPress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, curl, iframe

I'm trying to load content from other website to my wordpress website with cURL. The problem that I have is that links in the iframe are displayed like that are being loaded from my website.
Ie. in the original websites from where I pull the content there is link originalwebsite.com/product123 but on my website in the iframe i see mywebsite.com/product123 how to remove my website from all a hrefs and use original links?

These are my files:

redirect.php has this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
}
```

my page template has this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: i-frame
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div class="primary-inner_">
        <div id="content" class="site-content content-list" role="main">
        <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) : 
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <iframe id="elframe" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/redirect.php?url=http://www.partners..com/en/106597" frameborder="0" style="width:1020px; min-height:7935px; margin: 0 auto;display:block"></iframe>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php 
            endwhile;
        else : 
            get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); 
        endif; 
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```